Multiple versioned state machine
Assume that I have current State Machine for purchase requests with following flow (simplified for the purpose of discussion).

Request Flow ver 1.0 (Ongoing)

SUBMIT event initiates the workflow for a given purchase request and the state would be 'SUBMITTED'.
APPROVE event causes the request be 'APPROVED' by manager. All approved requests will be processed later by Purchase department (Out of scope of State Machine)


Request flow ver 1.1 (Effective for requests submitted from a given date)

SUBMIT event initiates the workflow for a given request and the state would be 'SUBMITTED'. (same as above)
MANAGER_APPROVE event causes the request be 'MANAGER_APPROVED' by manager.
If the value of the purchase request is up to $1000/- then it can directly be processed by Purchase department.
VP_APPROVE is required for the requests exceeding $1000/-. Up on approval by VP, the state will be 'VP_APPROVED'. Only then Purchase department can take up for further processing (Out of scope of State Machine)



Making the changes is not an issue. But the challenge is to ensure that transactions submitted after threshold date must follow flow version 1.1. The requests submitted before threshold date are still valid and must follow flow version 1.0. Both could be active until all old transactions are closed. Is this possible? How to associate versioned state machines with the transactions? Are there any sample implementations with this nature?

Can you be more specific? What exactly you struggling with. Keep in min that asking for libraries or tutorials is offtopic here.
